# High number of users fail to purchase my IAP. Is this to be expected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

After adding analytics to my app, I have seen a very high number of users reach an error when trying to purchase a product within my app. Not all fail though.

.03% of all my users reach the error
.002% of my users successfully purchase the product

It's been very hard for me to debug because when I test with different devices and different apple accounts, the purchase always succeeds.

The error event is called when either 0 SKProducts can be found (they must have no internet?), or when they attempt to purchase, the transaction reads SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed.

My question is, how should I go about debugging this? What is the normal percentage of users that fail to purchase a product (maybe their iCloud isn't setup correctly, or their payment is declined). I still get a relatively normal amount of revenue from the IAP, so clearly it is working for some people. Am I really missing out on all these purchases due to a bug, or is something else going on?

My purchase code looks like this. I am using a pod called IAPHelper. I am highly doubtful the pod is the problem, since I've switched it out and had the same results.

```
- (void)makePurchase {

    SKProduct* product =[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products objectAtIndex:0];
    [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap buyProduct:product
                               onCompletion:^(SKPaymentTransaction* trans){

        if(trans.error){
            [self showErrorPurchasing:trans.error];
        } else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
            [[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap provideContentWithTransaction:trans];
            [self purchaseSucceeded];
        } else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
            [self showErrorPurchasing:trans.error];
        } else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateDeferred) {
            [self hideHud];
        } else if(trans.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
            [self purchaseSucceeded];
        }
    }];
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your question directly but in terms of the code maybe this will help. When you do

```
SKProduct* product =[[IAPShare sharedHelper].iap.products objectAtIndex:0];
```

the `objectAtIndex` will crash if the array is empty. Either test the array to make sure it has products or use `firstObject` and then test if `firstObject` is `nil`. So in summary

```
SKProduct * product = [... firstObject];

if ( product )
{
  ... your code ...
}
else
{
  ... unable to read products / no connection ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your users might have cancelled the purchase without continuing. In that case, you will receive purchase failed state.

Check whether the error code 2, to identify a user purchase cancel event. Here's how I handle it in my swift project. Hope this helps.

```
case .failed:
let errorCode = (trans.error as? SKError)?.code
if (errorCode == .paymentCancelled) {
   //Handle cancelled purchase
}
```